# Assembly and bootloaders

Tags: macos, memory, assembly, bootloader

I wanted to start learning some assembly, and I have a few questions:

- What are good books/sites to learn Assembly?
- Where can I read more about Bootloaders?
- Where can I read more about Mac's architecture?
- Where I can information about flash memory, especially how it is read by the processor?

Comment: For Mac OS X architecture you want Amit Singh's book, *Mac OS X Internals*: http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Mac-OS-X-Internals/Amit-Singh/e/9780321278548/

Comment: I have an educational instruction set with a set of lessons for learning asm, I have had no feedback so I dont know if they are useful or not, maybe a half an hours time to go through it and get some basics http://github.com/dwelch67/lsasim

Comment: bootloaders are about a wide a topic as assembly language and what you can do with it.  They basically provide a shim/gasket/layer between the hardware turning on and the next layer of software and its assumptions, for example the assumptions may be that all the peripherals are enabled and out of reset and the memory system (Dram in particular) is up and running ready to be used as general purpose ram.  this can be as simple as setting the stack pointer and branching to main to as complicated as dram init, pcie init, etc.

Comment: for reading purposes flash is just slow read only memory.  there are various flavors the old parallel, the spi serial, i2c serial.  different technologies, nand, nor, etc.  these things affect how fast/slow it is relative to another choice, which affects how you should use it depending on your system and the task at hand, sometimes you want to run code from it, sometimes you want to get the code from the flash to ram then run in ram.  start downloading and reading datasheets on flash parts to understand more about it

Comment: Here's a little information about bootloaders: http://wiki.osdev.org/Rolling_Your_Own_Bootloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the assembler: all depends on the kind of assembler you want to lear. Motorolla, Intel, Arm, S390, ...

I liked the following sites (if you are a beginner):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm

http://w3.ufsm.br/rmbranco/cefet_files/Apostila/8086%20Assembly.pdf

Kind regards,
PB

Answer (score 0):

For the first two questions you can go through some useful resources [here](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/)

Book : "Assembly Language: Step by Step" is my suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the boot loaders, I have found a lot of web pages. Some of them more interesting than others of course. I liked the following ones:

http://dc0d32.blogspot.in/2010/06/real-mode-in-c-with-gcc-writing.html

http://fisnikhasani.com/building-your-own-bootloader/

I hope this gives you a start.

Kind regards,
PB